# Solving complicated expression in SymPy takes a long time

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve symbolically the following equations using sympy. I set the `simplify=False`, and `rational=False` in the `solve` as well and it helped a lot with eq7. But it did not help with e14 and it takes forever. How can I improve this? The same code in Matlab takes a few seconds!

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, Function

def dynamic_solver():
    # Define symbolic variables
    C_steps, O, Kc, Ko, kc, ko, S, Q, CB6F, RUB, kq, Kp1, Kp2, Kd, Kf, Ku, nl, nc, JP700_j, JP700_c, a2, a1, Abs, phi2P_a, phi2p_a, phi2u_a, q2_a, JP680_j, Vc_j, An_j, Ag_j, An_c, Ag_c, E, gtc, gm, Ca, Vc_c, Rd = symbols(
        'C_steps O Kc Ko kc ko S Q CB6F RUB kq Kp1 Kp2 Kd Kf Ku nl nc JP700_j JP700_c a2 a1 Abs phi2P_a phi2p_a phi2u_a q2_a JP680_j Vc_j An_j Ag_j An_c Ag_c E gtc gm Ca Vc_c Rd'
    )
    
    # Calculate S and gammas
    S = (kc / Kc) * (Ko / ko)
    gammas = O / (2 * S)
    
    # Define equations
    eq1 = JP700_j - (Q * CB6F * kq) / (Q + (CB6F * kq) / ((Abs - a2) * (Kp1 / (Kp1 + Kd + Kf))))    
    eq2 = eq1.subs(JP700_j, JP680_j * (1 - (nl / nc) + (3 + 7 * gammas / C_steps) / ((4 + 8 * gammas / C_steps) * nc)))    
    eq3 = eq2.subs(JP680_j, Vc_j * (4 * (1 + 2 * gammas / C_steps)))    
    eq4 = eq3.subs(Vc_j, Ag_j / (1 - gammas / C_steps))    
    eq5 = eq4.subs(Ag_j, An_j + Rd)    
    eq6 = eq5.subs(An_j, -(C_steps * E * gm + Ca * E * gm + 2 * C_steps * gm * gtc - 2 * Ca * gm * gtc) / (E + 2 * gm + 2 * gtc))    
    eq7 = solve(eq6, a2, dict=True,simplify=False,rational=False)
    
    # Pass out the first root
    eqA = Function('eqA')(Abs, C_steps, CB6F, Ca, E, Kc, Kd, Kf, Ko, Kp1, O, Q, Rd, gm, gtc, kc, ko, kq, nc, nl)
    eqA = eq7[0][a2]
    
    # Define equations for the second case
    eq8 = JP700_j - Q * a2 * phi2P_a * (1 - (nl / nc) + (3 + 7 * gammas / C_steps) / ((4 + 8 * gammas / C_steps) * nc))
    eq9 = eq8.subs(JP700_j, Q * CB6F * kq / (Q + CB6F * kq / ((Abs - a2) * (Kp1 / (Kp1 + Kd + Kf)))))
    eq10 = eq9.subs(phi2P_a, phi2p_a / (1 - phi2u_a))
    eq11 = eq10.subs(phi2p_a, (q2_a) * Kp2 / (Kp2 + Kd + Kf + Ku))
    eq12 = eq11.subs(phi2u_a, (q2_a) * Ku / (Kp2 + Kd + Kf + Ku) + (1 - q2_a) * Ku / (Kd + Kf + Ku))
    eq13 = eq12.subs(q2_a, 1 - (Q / (Q + CB6F * kq / ((Abs - a2) * (Kp1 / (Kp1 + Kd + Kf))))))
    eq14 = solve(eq13, a2, dict=True,simplify=False,rational=False)
    
    # Pass out the second root
    eqB = Function('eqB')(Abs, C_steps, CB6F, Kc, Kd, Kf, Ko, Kp1, Kp2, Ku, O, Q, kc, ko, kq, nc, nl)
    eqB = eq14[1][a2]
    
    return eqA, eqB

# Call the dynamic_solver function to obtain the equations eqA and eqB
eqA, eqB = dynamic_solver()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is slow because it is expanding the equation which leads to a large expression. You can avoid the expansion like this:

```
In [82]: factors = Mul.make_args(factor_terms(eq13.as_numer_denom()[0]))

In [83]: factors = [f for f in factors if f.has(a2)]

In [84]: print(factors[0])
(CB6F*kq*(Kd + Kf + Kp1) + Kp1*Q*(Abs - a2))**2

In [85]: print(factors[1])
8*Kp1*nc*(Abs - a2)*(C_steps*Ko*kc + Kc*O*ko)*(-CB6F*Ku*kq*(Kd + Kf + Kp1)*(Kd + Kf + Ku) - Kp1*Ku*Q*(Abs - a2)*(Kd + Kf + Kp2 + Ku) + (CB6F*kq*(Kd + Kf + Kp1) + Kp1*Q*(Abs - a2))*(Kd + Kf + Ku)*(Kd + Kf + Kp2 + Ku)) - Kp2*a2*(CB6F*kq*(Kd + Kf + Kp1) + Kp1*Q*(Abs - a2))*(Kd + Kf + Kp1)*(Kd + Kf + Ku)*(6*C_steps*Ko*kc + 7*Kc*O*ko + 8*nc*(C_steps*Ko*kc + Kc*O*ko) - 8*nl*(C_steps*Ko*kc + Kc*O*ko))
```

The first factor is easy to solve:

```py
In [86]: solve(factors[0], a2)
Out[86]: 
⎡Abs⋅Kp₁⋅Q + CB6F⋅Kd⋅kq + CB6F⋅Kf⋅kq + CB6F⋅Kp₁⋅kq⎤
⎢─────────────────────────────────────────────────⎥
⎣                      Kp₁⋅Q                      ⎦
```

The second factor is quadratic but expanding the polynomial expression leads to a large result. SymPy will try different approaches to simplify that down but I guess in this case it just does not simplify and so attempting simplification is slow. Perhaps simpler then is just to apply the quadratic formula directly e.g. this gives one of the roots:

```
In [87]: a, b, c = factors[1].as_poly(a2, domain=EX).all_coeffs()

In [97]: a = a.factor()

In [98]: b = b.factor()

In [99]: c = c.factor()

In [100]: print((-b + sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2*a))
(16*Abs*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1**2*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nl + 6*Abs*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc + 32*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Q*kc*nc + 16*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nc - 16*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nl + 12*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc + 24*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc*nl + 6*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc + 16*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Ku*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nl + 6*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc + 16*Abs*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1**2*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nl + 6*Abs*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc + 24*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc*nl + 6*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc + 16*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Ku*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nl + 6*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nl + 6*Abs*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc + 16*Abs*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1**2*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl + 7*Abs*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko + 32*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1**2*O*Q*ko*nc + 16*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc - 16*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl + 14*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko + 24*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl + 7*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko + 16*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nl + 7*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko + 16*Abs*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1**2*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl + 7*Abs*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko + 24*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl + 7*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko + 16*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nl + 7*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko + 8*Abs*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nl + 7*Abs*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**3*Ko*Kp1*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nl + 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Kf*Ko*Kp1*kc*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nl + 18*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1**2*kc*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nl + 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl + 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*kc*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nl + 18*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*kc*kq*nc + 48*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nc - 32*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nl + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl + 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq*nl + 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl + 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**3*Ko*Kp1*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nl + 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1**2*kc*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nl + 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl + 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq*nl + 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl + 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl + 6*CB6F*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**3*Kp1*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl + 7*CB6F*Kc*Kd**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kf*Kp1*O*ko*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl + 21*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*kq + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1**2*O*ko*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl + 14*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl + 7*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf**2*Kp1*O*ko*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl + 21*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1**2*O*ko*kq*nc + 48*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc - 32*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl + 28*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl + 14*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl + 7*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl + 14*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**3*Kp1*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl + 7*CB6F*Kc*Kf**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1**2*O*ko*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl + 14*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl + 7*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl + 7*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl + 14*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl + 7*CB6F*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq + sqrt(-32*Abs*Kp1**2*Q*nc*(C_steps*Ko*kc + Kc*O*ko)*(Abs*Kd**2*Kp1*Q + 2*Abs*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Q + Abs*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Q + Abs*Kd*Kp1*Ku*Q + Abs*Kf**2*Kp1*Q + Abs*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Q + Abs*Kf*Kp1*Ku*Q + CB6F*Kd**3*kq + 3*CB6F*Kd**2*Kf*kq + CB6F*Kd**2*Kp1*kq + CB6F*Kd**2*Kp2*kq + CB6F*Kd**2*Ku*kq + 3*CB6F*Kd*Kf**2*kq + 2*CB6F*Kd*Kf*Kp1*kq + 2*CB6F*Kd*Kf*Kp2*kq + 2*CB6F*Kd*Kf*Ku*kq + CB6F*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*kq + CB6F*Kd*Kp1*Ku*kq + CB6F*Kd*Kp2*Ku*kq + CB6F*Kf**3*kq + CB6F*Kf**2*Kp1*kq + CB6F*Kf**2*Kp2*kq + CB6F*Kf**2*Ku*kq + CB6F*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*kq + CB6F*Kf*Kp1*Ku*kq + CB6F*Kf*Kp2*Ku*kq + CB6F*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kq)*(8*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*kc*nc + 8*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*kc + 16*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*kc*nc + 16*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*nc - 16*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*nl + 12*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc + 16*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc + 8*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*nc + 8*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc + 8*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*kc*nc + 8*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc + 16*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc + 8*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*nc + 8*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc + 8*C_steps*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc + 8*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*O*ko*nc + 8*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*O*ko + 16*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*O*ko*nc + 16*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 16*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 14*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*O*ko + 16*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko + 8*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*nc + 8*Kc*Kd*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kd*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kd*Kp2*Ku*O*ko + 8*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*O*ko*nc + 8*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko + 16*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko + 8*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*nc + 8*Kc*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko + 8*Kc*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko) + (-16*Abs*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1**2*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nl - 6*Abs*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc - 32*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Q*kc*nc - 16*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nc + 16*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nl - 12*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc - 24*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc*nl - 6*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc - 16*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Ku*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nl - 6*Abs*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc - 16*Abs*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1**2*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc*nl - 6*Abs*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Q*kc - 24*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc*nl - 6*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Q*kc - 16*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Ku*Q*kc*nc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nl - 6*Abs*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc - 8*Abs*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nc + 8*Abs*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc*nl - 6*Abs*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*Q*kc - 16*Abs*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1**2*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl - 7*Abs*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko - 32*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1**2*O*Q*ko*nc - 16*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc + 16*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl - 14*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko - 24*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl - 7*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko - 16*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nl - 7*Abs*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko - 16*Abs*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1**2*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl - 7*Abs*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*Q*ko - 24*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko*nl - 7*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*Q*ko - 16*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc - 8*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nl - 7*Abs*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko - 8*Abs*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nc + 8*Abs*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko*nl - 7*Abs*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*Q*ko - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**3*Ko*Kp1*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nl - 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Kf*Ko*Kp1*kc*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nl - 18*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1**2*kc*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nl - 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl - 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*kc*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nl - 18*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*kc*kq*nc - 48*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nc + 32*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nl - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl - 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq*nl - 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1**2*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl - 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**3*Ko*Kp1*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq*nl - 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**3*Ko*Kp2*kc*kq - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1**2*kc*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq*nl - 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*kq - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl - 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq*nl - 6*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*kc*kq - 8*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1**2*Ku*kc*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl - 12*CB6F*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq - 16*CB6F*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq*nl - 6*CB6F*C_steps*Ko*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*kc*kq - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**3*Kp1*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl - 7*CB6F*Kc*Kd**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kf*Kp1*O*ko*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl - 21*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*kq - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1**2*O*ko*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl - 14*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl - 7*CB6F*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf**2*Kp1*O*ko*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc + 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl - 21*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1**2*O*ko*kq*nc - 48*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc + 32*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl - 28*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl - 14*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl - 7*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1**2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl - 14*CB6F*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**3*Kp1*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl - 7*CB6F*Kc*Kf**3*Kp2*O*ko*kq - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1**2*O*ko*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl - 14*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*kq - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl - 7*CB6F*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq*nl - 7*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Kp2*O*ko*kq - 8*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1**2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc - 24*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 16*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl - 14*CB6F*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq - 16*CB6F*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nc + 8*CB6F*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq*nl - 7*CB6F*Kc*Kp1**2*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*kq)**2))/(2*Kp1*Q*(8*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp1*kc*nc + 8*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kd**2*Ko*Kp2*kc + 16*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp1*kc*nc + 16*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*nc - 16*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc*nl + 12*C_steps*Kd*Kf*Ko*Kp2*kc + 16*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc + 8*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*nc + 8*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kd*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc + 8*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp1*kc*nc + 8*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kf**2*Ko*Kp2*kc + 16*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*kc + 8*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp1*Ku*kc*nc + 8*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Kf*Ko*Kp2*Ku*kc + 8*C_steps*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*nc - 8*C_steps*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc*nl + 6*C_steps*Ko*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*kc + 8*Kc*Kd**2*Kp1*O*ko*nc + 8*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kd**2*Kp2*O*ko + 16*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp1*O*ko*nc + 16*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 16*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 14*Kc*Kd*Kf*Kp2*O*ko + 16*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko + 8*Kc*Kd*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*nc + 8*Kc*Kd*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kd*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kd*Kp2*Ku*O*ko + 8*Kc*Kf**2*Kp1*O*ko*nc + 8*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kf**2*Kp2*O*ko + 16*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Kp2*O*ko + 8*Kc*Kf*Kp1*Ku*O*ko*nc + 8*Kc*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kf*Kp2*Ku*O*ko + 8*Kc*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nc - 8*Kc*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko*nl + 7*Kc*Kp1*Kp2*Ku*O*ko))
```

For the benefit of someone who does not want to scroll right far enough to see how large the expression is:

```
In [102]: len(str(((-b + sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2*a))))
Out[102]: 16979
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge expression which is just quadratic you can also get a solution in a compact form by using `cse` and you can use differentiation to get the coefficients without expanding the monster; the solution for factor[1] looks like this:

```py
def cse_quadratic(eq, x):
    A,B,C = [eq.diff(x,2)/2,eq.diff(x).subs(x,0),eq.subs(x,0)]
    D = sqrt(B**2 - A*C*4)
    return cse([(-B-D)/A/2, (-B+D)/A/2])
>>> r, e = cse_quadratic(factor[1], a2)
>>> from sympy import Eq
>>> for i in r: print(Eq(*i))
Eq(x0, Kp1*Q)
Eq(x1, Kd + Kf)
Eq(x2, Ku + x1)
Eq(x3, Kp2 + x2)
Eq(x4, Ku*x3)
Eq(x5, C_steps*Ko*kc)
Eq(x6, Kc*O*ko)
Eq(x7, x5 + x6)
Eq(x8, 8*x7)
Eq(x9, nc*x8)
Eq(x10, Kp1*x9)
Eq(x11, Abs*x10*(-x0*x2*x3 + x0*x4))
Eq(x12, Abs*x0)
Eq(x13, Kp1 + x1)
Eq(x14, CB6F*kq*x13)
Eq(x15, x12 + x14)
Eq(x16, -nl*x8 + 6*x5 + 7*x6 + x9)
Eq(x17, Kp2*x13*x15*x16*x2)
Eq(x18, -Ku*x14*x2 - x12*x4 + x15*x2*x3)
Eq(x19, x10*x18)
Eq(x20, Kp2*x13*x16*x2 + x1*x10*x3)
Eq(x21, -x11 + x17 + x19)
Eq(x22, sqrt(-32*Abs*Kp1**2*Q*nc*x18*x20*x7 + x21**2))
Eq(x23, 1/(2*Kp1*Q*x20))
>>> e # the two solutions for a2
[x23*(-x11 + x17 + x19 - x22), x23*(x21 + x22)]
```

If you want to evaluate by providing values for the variables you can see the two roots like this:

```py
syms = factor[1].free_symbols - {a2}
from random import randint
reps = {s: randint(1,10) for s in syms} # give symbols random values
V = [Tuple(*i).subs(reps) for i in r][::-1] # use those in the cse r and reverse
>>> [i.subs(V) for i in e] # feed into roots to get full expr
[141469861/4438406 - 5*sqrt(765562876168057)/4438406, 5*sqrt(765562876168057)/4438406 + 141469861/4438406]
>>> [i.n(2) for i in _]
[0.70, 63.]
```

(You have to reverse the replacements because later ones depend on early patterns that were identified.)